# Emacs pdb, printing JSON is slow

Tags: json, emacs, pdb

When I print a json string in emacs, it is really slow for a decently large json.

I guess it has something to do with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-handle-files-with-extremely-long-lines

Is there a way to pretty print json in pdb or other workaround?

I'm on python2.7 so pprint doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

pprint is available for python 2.7. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Also pdb (on Python 2.7) has a command that uses that and is called `pp`.

Finally, yes, emacs is very slow in printing very long lines of 1,000 characters or so.